# Is there a "product" aggregate for Dask Dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby, dask

I'm attempting to use Dask Dataframe to aggregate a large dataset.

My dd.df looks like this:

```
seq                                       kegg       evalue
AAAAAAAAPAADAKK                           K02897     0.001
AAAAAAAAPAADAKK                           K02897     0.007
AAAAAAAAPAPAPVAEEGEPIEHLPEITFDDFSKVELRVAR K01874     0.1
```

I'm trying to use groupby to:

1. count the number of times the same "kegg" is connected to each "seq"
2. Find the product of the "evalue" for each "kegg" connected to each "seq"

I've tried to use `groupby().agg()` using the following:

```
df.groupby(['seq','kegg']).agg({'kegg':['count'], 
'evalue':['prod']}, split_out=10)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: unknown aggregate prod
```

Looking through the documentation, it looks like there is a prod aggregate, but clearly this is not working.

I'm new to both pandas and dask, so I'm sure this is an easy fix that I'm just not getting.

Comment: Running your aggregation on dask 1.2.0 (without the .gene_list since I have the dataframe directly in df) gives me the correct result, so it would seem the prod aggregate exists and works. Not sure why you're seeing the problem though.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Oops, thanks for reminding me to take gene_list out of the question. interesting... maybe I will try reinstalling Dask...

Comment: In case anyone also has this problem...re-installation of Dask solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, this was resolved by installing a newer version of Dask